# What is a Written Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Written Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Written Words™ | Not Written Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| GOOD | BAD |
| JANUARY | DECEMBER |
| HAPPY | SAD |
| JOKER | CLOWN |
| GRAVEYARD | GRAVE |
| HYPER | SUPER |
| EIGHT | SEVEN |
| EGYPT | ISRAEL |
| POLICEMAN | FIREMAN |
| QUINTET | TRIO |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Written Words™,Not Written Words™
GOOD,BAD
JANUARY,DECEMBER
HAPPY,SAD
JOKER,CLOWN
GRAVEYARD,GRAVE
HYPER,SUPER
EIGHT,SEVEN
EGYPT,ISRAEL
POLICEMAN,FIREMAN
QUINTET,TRIO
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that a Written Word satisfies the property that

> If we write the word in lower case, it contains components which extend both above and below the standard [x-height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height) margins. In other words, the "height" of these words is more than two x-heights.

Examples

> "january" has descenders 'j' and 'y' which go below the line and the dot on the j which appears above.
>  "grave" is not a Written Word because it just has a descender but "graveyard" also ascends at the 'd' which makes it a Written Word.
>  "quintet" has the descender 'q' and, even though it's not generally considered an "ascender", 't' which does extend above the top x-height margin.

Comment: You got it, nice work~ :P